# FindBin wrong drive identification

Tags: perl, module, path

Let's consider the script:

```
use FindBin;
print "$FindBin::Bin\n";
```

Windows 7, `This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys`. It will produce the following:

```
C:\Test>perl catFileTest.pl
/c/Test
```

Perl is used extensively in our solution, for build and the correct path (`C:\Test`) is needed.

Comment: Strawberry `5.16.3` returns what you want, consider to upgrade as `5.8` is very old.

Comment: That appears to be the same archaic version of perl that is included in a Git for Windows install.  Fortunately many useful perl installs are also available.

Comment: @tjd, The problem has nothing to do with the version, as you can see from the answer posted an hour before your comment. You'll never get `C:\Test` as an absolute path in a unix environment, no matter what version of Perl you're using.

Comment: @ikegami, rather than intending to single out v5.8.8, my intent was to single out the specific implementation that comes with Git for Windows.  Perhaps my use of the word 'version' was unfortunate, but no applicable synonym came to mind.  While the dream is noble, I find bash implementations on Windows unfortunate when trying to pass paths to/from native executables....

Comment: @tjd, I see. Sorry I didn't understand, but "not useful archaic version" means something rather different than "non-Windows build". (I would also have tagged mpapec, but we can only tag one person per comment.)

Comment: It was indeed a version coming with "Git for Windows", I installed the corporate accepted version (ActivePerl or something), deleted the path added to "PATH" for those many "smart" tools and now it works.

Comment: Now I cannot accept that answer since I rather have the module work as expected rather than a workaround (but I tagged it as useful). I leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

msys utilities execute in a unix emulation. Inside that environment, `/c/Test` is indeed correct. `C:\Test` would mean "a file named `C:\Test` in the current work directory".

I don't know if `msys` provides a utility to convert paths like cygwin does. If not, you can use something like

```
s{^/([a-z])(?:/|\z)}{\u$1:};
s{/}{\\}g;
```